# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.rpc.Service

Tags: java, rest, soap, jersey, axis

I have created a dynamic web project in eclipse which uses Stubs generated using Axis to invoke some SOAP based web services. There is a java class which actually uses this stubs to generate the response. I have included the required axis jars in WEB-INF/lib.(Target Runtime- Tomcat 7). The project also has REST apis generated using Jersey which are used for some other REST web services invocation. I debugged the problem and found that when the control actually comes in the constructor of class using stubs it throws an exception as,

...
Jan 04, 2013 11:26:42 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException

SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/rpc/ServiceException
...

Following is the content of my web.xml related to servlets,

Jersey REST Service
               com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

```
            <init-param>
                    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
                    <param-value>{PackageName}</param-value>
            </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>{ResponseFilterClass}</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Am I missing any more dependencies? Because the class for which its giving exception, its jar is already included WEB-INF/lib
Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it could be a classloader issue. check that the same jar is not placed elsewhere in the appserver or in the boot classpath of the application server.

Comment: I did check with my WEB-INF/lib folder. There are no duplicate entries for jars. But, when I created the war, I observed that, I had created axislib folder in WEB-INF/lib and placed axis related jars there, but these jars werent included in the deployed folder created in Tomcat/WebApps for this project. So, I moved them from WEB-INF/axislib folder to WEB-INF/lib and it worked. Does tomcat ignore subfolder or userlibs while creating war file?

Comment: Servlet spec says that all jar used in your webapp must be under WEB-INF/lib other directories are not used for loading classes. under WEB-INF/lib you cannot specify subfolders, all jars must be at the WEB-INF/lib level.